# scala table row column implicit

Tags: scala, dsl, implicit

To get the hang of `implicits` in scala, I tried and did not quite manage to replicate the table example from Martin Odersky's talk (at time 41:22): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXDm3WHZT5g

Here is my attempt. It works except for the fact that I don't seem to be able to get rid of the implicits `thisTable` and `thisRow`:

```
object Prog {

  class Table {
    private var rows: Seq[Row] = Seq()
    def add(row: Row) = rows = rows :+ row
    override def toString(): String = {
      s"Table(${rows.mkString(", ")})"
    }
  }
  class Row {
    private var columns: Seq[Column] = Seq()
    def add(col: Column) = columns = columns :+ col
    override def toString(): String = {
      s"Row(${columns.map(_.content).mkString(", ")})"
    }
  }
  case class Column(content: String)

  def table(initTable: Table => Unit): Table = {
    val t = new Table()
    initTable(t)
    t
  }
  def row(initRow: Row => Unit)(implicit table: Table): Row = {
    val r = new Row()
    initRow(r)
    table.add(r)
    r
  }
  def cell(content: String)(implicit row: Row) = {
    row.add(new Column((content)))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val t:Table =
      table { implicit thisTable => // How can I get rid of this "implicit thisTable"?
        row { implicit thisRow => // How can I get rid of this "implicit thisRow"?
          cell("cellA1")
          cell("cellB1")
        }
        row { implicit thisRow =>
          cell("cellA2")
          cell("cellB2")
        }
      }
    println(t)
  }
}
```

How can I achieve the builder syntax as was shown in the talk?

I tried to move the `implicit` keyword in front of the parameter types in the `table` and `row` function, but as soon as I do that, the compiler starts barking at me in several places ("Wrong type", "missing parameter type: Table", "';' or newline expected", ....)

Thanks

Comment: you wanna get rid of implicit as well the params like thisTable/thisRow, right? Then I believe you need to use Scala dotty compiler: https://www.scala-lang.org/blog/2016/12/07/implicit-function-types.html That feature merged: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/1775

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember if this was mentioned explicitly in the talk, but *implicit functions* were a Dotty feature, on which the recently released Scala 3 is based.

In Scala 3, your example – including the [numerous other changes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/new-in-scala3.html) and the mentioned feature (now called [context functions](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/context-functions.html)) – would look as follows:

```
object Prog:
  class Table:
    private var rows: Seq[Row] = Seq()
    def add(row: Row) = rows = rows :+ row
    override def toString(): String = rows.mkString("Table(", ", ", ")")
    
  class Row:
    private var cells: Seq[Cell] = Seq()
    def add(cell: Cell) = cells = cells :+ cell
    override def toString(): String = cells.mkString("Row(", ", ", ")")
    
  case class Cell(content: String)

  def table(initTable: Table ?=> Unit): Table =
    given t: Table = Table()
    initTable
    t

  def row(initRow: Row ?=> Unit)(using table: Table): Row =
    given r: Row = Row()
    initRow
    table.add(r)
    r

  def cell(content: String)(using row: Row) =
    row.add(Cell((content)))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    val t =
      table {
        row {
          cell("cellA1")
          cell("cellB1")
        }
        row {
          cell("cellA2")
          cell("cellB2")
        }
      }
    println(t)
```

Note the new `given` and `using` keywords and the context function arrow `?=>`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `row` expects an `implicit table`.

```
def row(initRow: Row => Unit)(implicit table: Table): Row = {
    ...
  }
```

So either you provide `thisTable` as `implicit` as your solution does.

Or you have to provide `thisTable` and `thisRow` explicitly, like:

```
val t:Table =
  table {  thisTable => // No implicit here
    row {  thisRow => // No implicit here
      cell("cellA1")(thisRow) // But explicitly row
      cell("cellB1")(thisRow) // But explicitly row
    }(thisTable) // But explicitly table
    row { implicit thisRow =>
      cell("cellA2")(thisRow)
      cell("cellB2")(thisRow)
    }(thisTable)
  }
```

A good example on how much boilerplate you can avoid with `implicits`.